# Finding out the number of combinations to crack a password?

Tags: java, .net, passwords

How do you calculate how many combinations someone has to try to crack a password?
Imagine the password is:
"Input 1"
Char = 26 + 26 + 33 + 10 = 95

Is there any way to calculate the number of combinations?
I currently just use `95^a` - a being the password length... is this an accurate equation?

Comment: Basic, elementary mathematics is what you need to think of.  Think of the number of possibilities for each character to begin with.

Comment: Yes, there's a way. It's called combinatorics. I didn't follow your 95-logic.

Comment: Checked the Wiki - doesn't return any equations, just theoretical.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about elementary mathematics.  Might be on-topic at http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yes it's very theory-heavy, but that's wikipedia on math for you. You might want to find something simpler.

Comment: About the "95-logic", capitals have an ascii range of 26 - same as noncapitals. So the pass "Ab" has to range the whole capital alphabet and the noncapital alphabet (in ascii). So "Ab" has a range of 26 + 26...

Comment: There's a guide at [XKCD](http://xkcd.com/936/). Careful though, it's a highly technical resource.

Comment: @duozmo Is that the password entropy one?

Comment: @devnull You don't click links? :p

Comment: @keyser To be honest, usually not.  In this case, I could have but guessing was probably easier.

Comment: Say you have two digits, each can be 0 to 9.  How many combinations can you get from two of them? 10 * 10, if you have three digits, you have 10 * 10 * 10.  If you have 95 possibly symbols and N of them then the combinations is 95^N.  Note: you don't know the actual length so it is 95  + 95^2 + 95^3 + ... + 95^N

Answer (score 2):

It depends if you know the length of the password. If it is in principle unbounded (eg, any length is possible) then there's an infinite amount of possibilities.

If you know the length is N, then you only need to determine how many values a single place can take. My guess is you already know this: 26 for lower case letters, 26 for upper case letters, 10 for digits, and 33 (for special characters?). In your case this adds up to 95, and then the number of combinations is 95^N. Ergo, your assumption is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation ;)

Comment: @user3422952 - Note that 95 is the base not the exponent, Mark wrote correctly `95^n`, but in your example you wrote `n^95` which is wrong.